# How to save HABTM in CakePHP 2.4?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

A Car HABTM Image in the the table `cars_images`

```
Array
(
    [Car] => Array
        (
            [country_id] => 1
            [body_type_id] => 7
            [published] => 0
            [variant] => 4 cyl AWD
        )
    [Image] => Array
        (
            [image_url] => files/cars/subaru/outback/2012/Outback-3.6R3.jpg
        )
)
```

The car is being saved. The image is not (no record is being created, not in the `images` table nor in the `cars_images` table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a form looks like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Image.0.image_url');
echo $this->Form->input('Image.1.image_url');
echo $this->Form->input('Image.2.image_url');
```

So, produce this:

```
Array
(
    [Car] => Array
        (
            [country_id] => 1
            [body_type_id] => 7
            [published] => 0
            [variant] => 4 cyl AWD
        )
    [Image] => Array
        (
           [0] => Array
                (
                    [image_url] => files/cars/subaru/outback/2012/Outback-3.6R3.jpg
                )
           [1] => Array
                (
                    [image_url] => files/cars/subaru/outback/2012/Outback-3.6R3.jpg
                )
           [2] => Array
                (
                    [image_url] => files/cars/subaru/outback/2012/Outback-3.6R3.jpg
                )
        )
)
```

And use `saveAll`:

```
$this->Car->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

You can find more information **[here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)**.

Comment: Thanks but this did not work. I was wondering if it is not working because the Car entry does not exist and I am not supplying the ID of the Car in the Car array. I solved the issue by saving all the images and the habtm association in the afterSave() call-back in the Car model but this not the "cakish" way

Answer (score 0):

For HABTM the array structure must(in your case)

```
(
    [Car] => Array
        (
            [country_id] => 1
            [body_type_id] => 7
            [published] => 0
            [variant] => 4 cyl AWD
        )

    [Image] => Array
        (
            [Image] => Array
                  (
                    [0] => Array
                      (
                         [image_url] => files/cars/subaru/outback/2012/Outback-3.6R3.jpg
                      )
                  )
        )
)
```

And to "save the data" need to use

```
$this->Car->saveAll($data);
```

Comment: Tried this, did not work. The saving in the Image is not even being called although I have the relationships defined in all 3 models...

Comment: if possible please add the model associations in the question as well the view code and controller action code

Comment: If i insert the Car id into the Car array, it saves normally so my associations are correct. But the thing is it seems that it is not supported out of the box to create the entry into Car , then into Image and then save the HABTM association between them..